# how to upload file via request payload using curl php

Tags: php, api, curl, request, payload

I do not have access of back end server and i analysed the API via network. I want to upload file using that API.I have observed that there are no parameters in post request to that API .I observed  request payload in network .

> Response Header

Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:135
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Sat, 06 Aug 2016 14:32:00 GMT
Location:http://myURL
Server:nginx/1.2.3
Set-Cookie:_mystore2_session=BAh7CEkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRkkiJTAxYzJhNTBkYmY3ZTRkYTBhYmY4NzhjNzdmNGY5OWRhBjsAVEkiEF9jc3JmX3Rva2VuBjsARkkiMXB0WEl6NnZKSnF2ZVNCTTVXdnEzODdqWkc0cXFsN1RiTDB4d3o4WWo2aUE9BjsARkkiGXdhcmRlbi51c2VyLnVzZXIua2V5BjsAVFsISSIQU3ByZWU6OlVzZXIGOwBGWwZpAzggAUkiGXk0MTFIUTdVUktORkh2MzFCeEtFBjsARg%3D%3D--63863b861eb33b48b3137d187b2113fe90a930f3; path=/; HttpOnly
Status:302 Found
X-Rack-Cache:invalidate, pass
X-Request-Id:3c843dc4dcb55bcf5f15e139264fa9be
X-Runtime:0.884597
X-UA-Compatible:IE=Edge,chrome=1

> Request Header

Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:642389
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary2rjUr5SSxx3BXjGn
Cookie:s=; lat_lon=33.69%2673.0551; __utmt=1; _mystore2_session=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--c3c1b5d437fd04a80dc888822811d2d4d354ae29; __utma=129180296.2104761345.1470477279.1470488831.1470491357.3; __utmb=129180296.10.9.1470493699533; __utmc=129180296; __utmz=129180296.1470477279.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
Host:www.usedmotorcycles.net
Origin:myURL
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:myURL
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36

> Request Payload

------WebKitFormBoundary2rjUr5SSxx3BXjGn
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="utf8"

✓
------WebKitFormBoundary2rjUr5SSxx3BXjGn
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="authenticity_token"

ptXIz6vJJqveSBM5Wvq387jZG4qql7TbL0xwz8Yj6iA=
------WebKitFormBoundary2rjUr5SSxx3BXjGn
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image[attachment]"; filename="Screenshot (156).png"
Content-Type: image/png

How i can use curl payload to submit my file?

Comment: I don't know why you expect us to debug this using only headers when the problem is possibly in your code. [Check out the MVCE page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on what would help your question along

Comment: i have to observe from headers and request payload that what parameter should i sent ? this is post request and i did not observed form parameters

Comment: `I have observed that there are no parameters in post request to that API` Wrong, there's a bunch of parameters, to name a few: `Cookie:s`, `lat_lon`, `__utmt`, `_mystore2_session`, `__utma` , AND MORE

Answer (score 1):

quote: `I have observed that there are no parameters in post request to that API`
Wrong, there's a bunch of parameters, to name a few: `Cookie:s`, `lat_lon`, `__utmt`, `_mystore2_session`, `__utma`, AND MORE.

Also, that's not the complete request header you're showing us. for one, it's missing the 
request type (though its probably a POST request)
anyway, to replicate this with curl, it's something like:

```
<?php 
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch,array(
CURLOPT_URL=>'???',
CURLOPT_ENCODING=>'',
CURLOPT_POST=>true,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>array(
'Cookie:s'=>'',
'lat_lon'=>'33.69&73.0551',
'_mystore2_session'=>'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--c3c1b5d437fd04a80dc888822811d2d4d354ae29',
'image'=>array(new CURLFile('/path/to/file.png','image/png','Screenshot (156).png'))
//and more post data here.

),
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=>array(
'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,/;q=0.8',
'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8',
'Cache-Control: no-cache',
'Pragma: no-cache',
'Origin: myURL',
//and more headers here
),
CURLOPT_USERAGENT=>'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36',
));
curl_exec($ch);
```

**note**: this is NOT the complete code, it's missing a bunch of data for `CURLOPT_POSTFIELD` and `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` , but this should get you started